# Why Krishna is called Kunj Bihari?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, puranas, bhagavata-purana, name

I want to know why Lord Krishna is called Kunj Bihari.

Comment: http://www.krishna.com/forums/what-does-kunja-beehari-mean  You can see this.

Comment: Lord Krishna is called Kunj Bihari beause Bihari means who always go to spend time like Krishna everyday went to spend time with Radha. There is also the word Kunj because Kunj means so much beautiful garden and Krishna went to spend time with Radha in a beautiful garden.

Answer (score 5):

This name comes from ["Jaya Radha Madhava"](http://www.harekrsna.com/practice/sadhana/morning/bhagavatam/jayaradha.htm), a poem by the Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharaya Bhaktivinoda Thakur:

> (jaya) radha-madhava **(jaya) kunja-vihari** 
>  (jaya)
>   gopi-jana-vallabha (jaya) giri-vara-dhari 
>  (jaya) jasoda-nandana
>   (jaya) braja-jana-ranjana 
>  (jaya) jamuna-tira-vana-cari
>
> Krsna is the lover of Radha. **He displays many amorous pastimes in
>   the groves of Vrndavana**, He is the lover of the cowherd maidens of
>   Vraja, the holder of the great hill named Govardhana, the beloved son
>   of mother Yasoda, the delighter of the inhabitants of Vraja, and he
>   wanders in the forests along the banks of the River Yamuna.

So it refers to Krishna's romantic pastimes amidst the groves of Vrindavana.

Comment: Literally 'Kunj' means Arbour, ie, a shady garden alcove with the sides and roof formed by trees and 'Vihari' means who goes there to spend time. So, 'Kunj-Vihari' means Lord Krishna, the one who goes to or likes spending time in the beautiful gardens which are shady from different sides.